# Jquery disable/enable checkbox on input text change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to disable a checkbox if input text is not empty and enable the same checkbox if the input text is empty. When the input text is not empty, the disable works but when input text is cleared out the enable part doesn't work.

```js
  $('#userId').on('change paste keyup', function () {
     if ($(this).val() !=='') {
      $("#vendorId").prop("disabled", true);
      }else{
       $("#vendorId").prop("disabled", false);
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="userId" placeholder="user's name">
  
   <div>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="vendorId" value="vendor">
        Vendors
       </label>
      </div>
```

Comment: Your checkbox's `id` is not `vendor` but `admin`.

Comment: I have fixed it. It was an error

Comment: Now it seems to work for me (though I'd suggest using `input` instead of `change paste keyup`). Are there still any problems?

Comment: It works only on disable still not enable. I have made the following changes   $('#userId').on('propertychange input', function ()

Comment: This works for me now  $('#userId').on('input', function ()